# How do I force csv format in a short answer on a Google form?

Tags: google-forms, regex

so I'm trying to make a google form where a person will need to input either one single number or a series of numbers in a short answer, while necessarily using the comma separators between the different numbers. There should be no limit to the number of characters for each of the numbers.

**Example of correct inputs:**

2

123

123123123123123123123123

123123123123,12341235

1234123412341234,0102020,000122123

**Example of incorrect inputs:**

1.2 (no decimals should be accepted)

asdasdasd (has non numeric characters)

123123123;12312313 (has the incorrect separator)

123123123, 123123123 (has a space between the comma and the next number)

123123123,123123123, (has a comma at the end, but is not followed by any other numbers)

This is my first contact with regular expressions, so I'm struggling a lot. I've searched everywhere and couldn't figure it out by myself. Hope you guys can help me.

Edit:

I was able to make it work with the query below:

^\d{1,1000}(,\d{1,1000})*$

However, is there an expression I can use other than {1,1000}? I basically don't care if it has one or infinite characters, it just needs to be a whole number

Answer (score 0):

Simply omit the upper bound, like this:

`^\d{1,}(,\d{1,})*$`

You did not specify whether leading and repeated commas should be allowed. If they are to be allowed, you can accept digits and commas in any order, but without a trailing comma, with this regular expression:

`^[\d,]+\d$`

To learn the exact [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) syntax used by Google Sheets, see [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).